# Installing Jython on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, bash, jython

I want to install [Jython](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jython) on Mac OS X. Sofar so good, after installing Jython 2.5.2. and creating an alias in `.profile` I am now able to run Jython. However I cannot use [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/) and [Easy Install](http://packages.python.org/distribute/easy_install.html) because it looks in the current directory. How do I adjust this?

```
iMac:~ admin$ jython pip something
IOError: [Errno 2] File not found - /Users/admin/pip (No such file or directory)
```

I guess I should setup a virtual environment for Jython, but I get this error:

```
iMac:~ admin$ jython virtual-env.py --prefix ~/Jython/
This script only works on Unix-like platforms, sorry.
```

Answer (score 2):

1. download ez_setup.py first and run it with jython first
2. download the pip source code archive, unpack it and run the setup.py script with the jython interpreter
3. run /path/jython/bin/pip...

Comment: A variation of the above also works for me, on Mac OS X Snow Leopard (and on Ubuntu): Download the setuptools source and unpack it. Within its source directory, run "jython setup.py install". Then, run "/path/to/jython/bin/easy_install pip". From that point forward, "/path/to/jython/bin/pip" works fine.

Answer (score 2):

The best and easiest way to do this is to first get [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), which is very easy.

When you have Homebrew you type

```
brew install jython
```

Comment: I use Jython within a virtual environment I've built with virtualenvwrapper (see http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). With this you can point to any python binary, including jython. So I have  done this (after installing jython with brew):
`mkvirtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/jython my_new_venv `. This way when I type `python` to get the python prompt, it already has all the jython environment loaded, and it doesn't interfere with the rest of my python installation.

Comment: If I want to choose the jython version?